# SQL Server: how to determine a column algorithm encryption

Tags: security, encryption

I have a table with a column, `Column_Password`, where I can see the password encrypted.

How can I know what type of algorithm encryption the column is using? How can I find if it's `sha1`, `MD5`, `sha256` or whatever?

My goal is to check if the password is present in [this massive database](http://www.cmd5.org/)

Comment: None of `sha1`, `MD5`, `sha256` are *encryption* - they are all *hashing*

Comment: Do you mean you have a collection of hashed values and you want to guess what hash was used to produce them? If so, certainly for the three hash algorithms you give, one early guess is easy - these three produce different sizes of hash!! (160, 128, 256 bits respectively)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.columns` system catalog view.

Details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql

[image]